# Appropriate use of UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am building my first "real" iOS app and want to make sure that I'm going down the sane path.

Distilled to its essence, the app will provide three distinct ways of visualizing a set of data.  Not counting any possible modal confirmation views, I am currently envisioning that I will need 6 UIViews (or subclasses thereof).  The first three each provide a unique way of visualizing the data.  The fourth will be a table view to select which data set is to be viewed.  The final two will form a parent/child heirarchy and will be used to display/edit user preferences for customizing the visualizations---one to display the list of data sets and the other to display details of a single selected data set.

My **initial** plan for the HMI is for the user to be able to sweep left/right between the views OR to select the view from a segmented control in the right position in the navigation bar.  The user can access the preference view via a gear icon in the left position of the navigation bar (which will change to "back" when the preferences are being displayed).  The title position will contain a button showing the name of the current data set and will trigger bringing up the list of data sets.  Selecting one of the data sets make the current data sets. Swiping a data set or a long press on it will bring up its details view.

There will also be a number (4 or 5) of items in a toolbar for recording/editing/saving/sharing the data within the dataset.  This will not be visible when viewing/editing preferences or the data set list.

My question is whether or not it makes sense to wrap all of this in a UINavigationController or if I want to use a custom controller, UINavigationBar, and UIToolbar.  It seems that using the navigation controller will simplify the code necessary to use the navigation and tool bars.  But, I am wondering if the mixture of hierarchal views and non-heirarchal (peer?) views (the data visualization views) will cause me undue headaches.

Thoughts?
Thanks!
mike

*p.s. I'm thinking that the benefits of using the UINavigationContrtoller will win out, but I wanted to see if anyone knows of a reason that this is a bad approach.*

Edit: I added the following figure per suggestion that it might help clarify my vision of the HMI.

[image: Napkin Storyboard]

Comment: Might be useful to add a diagram to show how how this will look. A picture is worth a thousand words, after all

Comment: Yeah... I thought about adding a figure. But I went "old school" on the initial storyboarding of my concept (pencil/paper).  I don't have a scanner near at hand and balked at redrawing it electronically.... but I will do so and add it to the discussion

Comment: Use your iPhone camera?

Comment: not with me right now... not allowed to bring camera (or any recording device) into my work location

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swipe left & right between view controllers, or tap on a page control, it sounds like you should be looking at a `UIPageViewController`

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

You implement 2 delegate methods, one to supply the page after a given view controller, the other to return the page before…

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

}
```

To have a "circular" set of pages, just return the view controller for page[0] after the view controller for the last page, and return the last page when before page[0]

Comment: I did look at using a UIPageViewController as an option as well, but wasn't sure if I could create a "circular" set of "pages".   1->2->3->1->2->3->....  The examples didn't seem to show that as an option.   I will look again. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "circular" pages are no problem - see updated answer

Comment: duh... so obvious, I never thought to try it.  (wiping egg off face)